# Print Second's level array in 3d Arrays PHP / Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this array :

```
A = [S1][P1,P2,P3][S1]
      1      2     3
```

I want to print the second's array like : 'P1,P2,P3'

I've tried to using for and foreach method. But no use or maybe i have wrong to write the method.

Could you help me about this ?

Comment: Are S1, P1,P2,P3, S1 variables or are they just strings?

Comment: @Mark : Yes they are.. Actually i convert it into json_encode from PHP. Like this : $a['S1']['P1,P2,P3'] = ['S1']; And then var a = <?php echo json_encode($a);?>;

Comment: So from what I understand, "S1", "P1,P2,P3" are keys, rather than values. Is that correct? And you want to print the exact text "P1,P2,P3"?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the array key values in JavaScript, you need to use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

In your case, running `Object.keys(a)` will return `["S1","P1,P2,P3"]`.

If you want to get the array key of the second item in the array, use `Object.keys(a)[1]`.